# Django demand login in url

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have a Django page with content that changes depending on whether the user is authenticated or not (more content when the user is authenticated)

Is there a way to provide an URL to this page, but login the user first if he's not logged in, and do nothing if the user is already logged in?

There is the `https://www.example.com/login/?next=/mypage/` syntax, but this will ask for a login even if the user is already logged in.

Any way to achieve this easily?

Comment: You can write the logic in the *login view*, how does your login view (view corresponding to `/login/` )look like?

Comment: So the page *can* be visited either logged in or anonymously. So providing a link directly to the page is valid either way, the page won’t and by definition can’t force the authentication redirect. But you want to provide a link to the page which *does* force authentication if not already logged in? How about an extra query param like `?auth=req`, which you can check in that particular view or with a custom authentication middleware and redirect based on it?